# Retrieve hard drive information from dead Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware

I have spilled a little bit of water around my Macbook Pro and some if obviously got into the computer because it won't turn on anymore -- force booting it gives me the flashing "? folder" thing.

So what I was wondering/hoping/praying is that someone knew a way that I can retrieve the info from a 2015 15' Macbook Pro's hard drive in any way. I know there have been ways in the past such as taking out the hard drive and basically buying a piece that converts it into an external hard drive. Not sure this is still an option?

I am a college student and have little money, so the cheapest option that works is what I am shooting for -- not the $300 option where I send it to Apple or the $1300 option where Apple fixes it.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how/why yours is broken - If you know someone with another Mac with Thunderbolt you can connect the two together and use your hard-drive to boot his laptop. Apple's instructions are here: https://support.apple.com/kb/ph10725?locale=en_US It's the same procedure across all recent OS versions.

Otherwise, you need something like this to pull our the M2 SSD, and turn it into a standard desktop external drive: [https://www.amazon.com/ZTC-Enclosure-Adapter-SuperSpeed-ZTC-EN004-BK/dp/B00KQ4LNJC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KQ4LNJC) or [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-M-2-SATA-External-Enclosure/dp/B00T8F298Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T8F298Y)

Goes without saying though, if the drive is broken, doesn't what you or how you plug it in - it's broken.

Further reading: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-upgrade-ssd-storage.html

Comment: Thank you! I am going to the Apple Store with an external hard drive once again to see if they are able to do this today.